# Show/Hide JLabel with button?

Tags: java, swing

Currently the code only hides the JLabel. I'm not sure why it's not making it visible when I click the button again. Hopefully this is an easy fix

```
        contentPane.add(btnSwap);   
    btnHide.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            lblHello.setVisible(false);
        }
    }); 
    contentPane.add(btnHide);
    btnHide.setBounds(185, 199, 89, 23);
    lblHello.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: You haven't provided the full code, but I suggest make sure you revalidate the parent of `lblHello` object so it is repainted to reflect your change.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm not sure why it's not making it visible when I click the button again.

Why should it, since all the ActionListener does (the code that's called on button press) is to continually set the label invisible?

A solution is to simply toggle its visibility:

```
lblHello.setVisible(!lblHello.isVisible());
```

Note that to be safe, it's best to revalidate and repaint the container after making such changes, so:

```
btnHide.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        lblHello.setVisible(!lblHello.isVisible());
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
});
```

as this will rid the GUI of "dirty" pixels that can occur from adding and especially from removing visible components.

---

A word on this:

```
btnHide.setBounds(185, 199, 89, 23);
```

This suggests that you're using null layouts with `setBounds(...)`. While this often seems to newbie Swing coders the best way to create complex GUI's, it will come back to haunt them later, since this will mean that the GUI will look OK on one platform and one platform only, and that if later you want to enhance or improve the GUI, it can only be done with much difficulty and risk of bugs.  Much better is to learn and use the layout managers.

---

Another recommendation:

If your desire is to change the appearance of the GUI on button press, then also have a look at the CardLayout (please check the [CardLayout Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)) as this can be a way to cleanly and easily swap *views*

---

And a better recommendation:

Since a JLabel only shows its text or its icon or both, the best way to make it "invisible" is to remove its text and its icon, as noted by Andrew Thompson below:

```
// get rid of its text
lblHello.setText("");

// and if needed
lblHello.setIcon(null);
```

This won't work for text components such as JTextFields and JTextAreas or other components that have more "heft" than a JLabel including pretty much all other user-interaction components.

Comment: *"If your desire is to change the appearance of the GUI on button press, then also have a look at the CardLayout"* that seems the best suggestion to me. Having said that, another way (OK a hack) to make a label disappear is `label.setIcon(null); label.setText("");`

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Said to you: "of course,  you are absolutely right!" Said to myself: "D'oh!!"

Comment: I still prefer the `CardLayout` idea though. Removing the text or icon from the label might change the position of other components. This is fresh in my memory from 'fixing' a label from moving other components when the text changed, by swapping it out for a text field that had been configured to **look like** a label (oh boy, the hacks come thick and fast!). ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
btnChangeLabelVisibilityButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        lblHello.setVisible(!lblHello.isVisible());
    }
});
```